# NullReferenceException was Unhandled by User Code Error

Tags: c#, .net, object, exception, null

I have 3 projects working fine separately but now I need to combine them in one file and I did it. Now I'm facing problem at the time of sending email after executing the query. Query works fine and there is no problem. I could't understand where is the problem in my code?

```
HiddenField tada = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("tada");

if (tada.Value == "4")
{
    // approved
    oda2.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"update kamran.crp_mov_ord 
                                  set sta_flg=15, rnd_cod='" + appcode +@"' 
                                  where mor_num='" + item["mor_num"].Text + "'";
    if (oda2.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        dsMove.Tables["dirdata"].Rows.Add(new object[] { item["mor_num"].Text, item["emp_nom"].Text, item["dsg_des"].Text, item["dpt_des"].Text, item["dst"].Text, item["pur_dty"].Text, item["sty_frm"].Text, item["sty_too"].Text, "Director Approved", comment, appcode });
    }
}
else
{

    // approved
    oda2.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"update kamran.crp_mov_ord 
                                  set sta_flg=2, rnd_cod='" + appcode +@"' 
                                  where mor_num='" + item["mor_num"].Text + "'";
    if (oda2.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        dsMove.Tables["dirdata"].Rows.Add(new object[] {tem["mor_num"].Text, item["emp_nom"].Text, item["dsg_des"].Text, item["dpt_des"].Text, item["dst"].Text, item["pur_dty"].Text, item["sty_frm"].Text, item["sty_too"].Text, "Director Approved", comment, appcode });
    }
```

I am getting NullReferenceException in IF condition after executing the query.

Comment: Is the UpdateCommand object being instantiated before that block code? How are you creating the adapter?

Comment: You shouldn't build SQL queries using strings like that, as they are vurnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters instead.

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please add the full exception, message and stack trace.

Comment: It's impossible to help given the limited info. Luckily, it should be easy for *you* to fix by stepping through the code in debugger and seeing what's Null. Could be dsMove, table dirData, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much [nunzabar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036274/nunzabar). I got where the problem was? There are three custom datasets created and I forget to set one dataset name to match with "dirdata".